# Bug in reversing word order

Tags: c, string

I am a beginner to C programming and am trying to "Split a string into separate words and write the string in reverse".

Sample Input : `Hello World it's FUBAR`

Sample Output: `FUBAR it's World Hello`

I have tried it with this code so far on CodeBlocks 13.12(Windows 8.1/AMD A8) :

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<string.h>

   char str[100];
   char word[100][100];



    int main(){
        fgets(str,100,stdin);
        int i=0,j=0,k=0;
        for(i=0;i<100;i++){
            while(str[i]!=' ' || str[i]!='\0')
            {
            word[j][k]=str[i];
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        if(str[i]==' '){
            k++;
            }
        }
    while(k>0){
        for(j=0;j<100;j++){
            printf("%s",word[j]);
            }
        printf(" ");
        k--;
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

The code compiles with 0 errors, 0 warnings.

But when I build and run the code, it crashes with error message -1073741510.
I have been trying for many hours now but have not been able to figure out where exactly the code is breaking.Please help me with this one.

Comment: Does CodeBlocks not have an integrated debugger?

Comment: Use your debugger to breakpoint/step thorugh the code execution.  Simples.

Comment: It can then be useful if you use a simple entry such as `"012 45"` because the character will also tell you the index it came from.

Comment: It's been only 3-4 weeks since I started C programming. So I am yet to understand how to use the debugger. I will try it in the future thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code.
1) Eliminated extra looping.
2) Swapped j and k variables . Each row would constitute a new word.
3) word[0][1..100] would the first word and word[1][1..100] would be second word.

```
int main(){
    fgets(str,100,stdin);
    printf("str is [%s]\n",str);
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    for(i=0;i<100;i++){
        printf("char is [%c]\n",str[i]);
        if(  str[i]!=' ' &&  str[i]!='\0' )
        {
            word[j][k]=str[i];
            k++;
        }else if(isspace(str[i]) || str[i] == ' '){
           printf("space found\n");
            j++;
        }
    }
    printf("value of j [%d]\n",j);
    while(j>=0){
        for(k=0;k<100;k++){
            printf("%c",word[j][k]);
        }
        printf(" ");
        j--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried this code with ideone and it works well ( [link] http://ideone.com/lmbe8f ) . However when I try it with CodeBlocks, I get the output with heavy amount of padding(Screenshot here : [link] http://i.imgur.com/AvbqnrT.jpg ). How do I go about this thing ?

Comment: There is new line which is showing up in the output. Change the line 7 to                                     if(  str[i]!=' ' &&  str[i]!='\0' && str[i] != '\n' )

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop looks wrong, it should be

```
for(i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    while(str[i]!=' ' || str[i]!='\0')
    {
        word[j][k]=str[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    if(str[i]==' ')
    {
        j++;
    }
}
```

Notice the `k` and `j` increment swap.

Answer (score 0):

In the first while increase k instead of j.
In if(str[i]==' ')  set the null termination for word[j][k] and then increase j instead of k.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a Corrected Code. Note the Output doesn't come exactly in one single line. For example the output will always come like this,

**EDIT: Thanks to a point reminded by Rad Lexus in the comments. I was able to mitigate the problem a bit**

**Changes made in Code:**

Changed the following code line to

```
for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
```

This,

```
for(i=0;i<strlen(str)-1;i++)
```

Although, the problem of outputting all the words in the same line is solved,
but there is another problem. Now there is no space between the first and the Second word.

So, the new problem is,

Example 1:

```
Input: Welcome to Bravo
Output: Bravoto Welcome
```

Example 2:

```
 Input: Hello World it's FUBAR
 Output: FUBARit's World Hello
```

A temporary solution to the above problem is to change this code

```
 for(m=j;m>=0;m--){
        printf("%s",word[m]);
    }
```

To this code,

```
   for(m=j;m>=0;m--){
    if(m == j){
        printf("%s ",word[m]);
    }
    else{
        printf("%s",word[m]);
    }
}
```

(I guess this problem occurs due to mapping from a 1D Array to a 2D Array and there is probably some padding involved.) ->  **Edit:This is not due to padding but,** ***"I guess this problem occurs due to.." – no, it occurs due to fgets which also stores the terminating newline code-Rad Lexus.***

Anyways, here is the code,

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>

 char str[100];
 char word[100][100];

 int main(){

    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    int m=0;

    fgets(str,100,stdin);

    for(i=0;i<strlen(str)-1;i++){
        if(str[i]!=' '){
            word[j][k]=str[i];
            //printf("%c",word[j][k]);
            k++;
        }
        if(str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\0'){
            word[j][k]=' ';
            k=0;
            j++;
        }
    }
    for(m=j;m>=0;m--){
        printf("%s",word[m]);/*----->TEMPORARY SOLUTION
                                      for(m=j;m>=0;m--){
                                         if(m == j){
                                            printf("%s ",word[m]);
                                         }
                                          else{
                                            printf("%s",word[m]);
                                          }
                                        }*/
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I guess this problem occurs due to.." – no, it occurs due to `fgets` which also stores the terminating newline code.

Comment: @Rad lexus Thanks for reminding me that I forgot about fgets storing  newline code.